# sailsjs .tmp folder not updated or created automatically

Tags: node.js, sails.js

In Sailsjs there is **.tmp** folder which holds all static content which is mainly from assets folder.

But
 1. the .tmp does not get updated after the changes in the asset folder (example index.html file)
 2. the .tmp is not automatically generated when the sails is cloned from git and .tmp folder is missing.

Is it the default behavior of .tmp folder or is there a way to fix this.?

Sails v0.11.5, node v0.4.4.2

Comment: Try running sails with --silly . There is Grunt debug. Maybe there will be some clue what is wrong. I think it may be something with privileges in your project.

Comment: It works in next way: you have some files in assets folder, when you run you r sails application, sails starts [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) and Grunt copy (actually it does much more) files from asset folder to .tmp folder. If it doesn't work you need to check if have Gruntfile.js and "tasks" folder at the root of project, also grunt can be turned off - check file .sailsrc

Comment: I had disabled grunt in order to prevent memory leak in my .sailsrc file. Learnt what generates .tmp folder. Is there any other to keep .tmp folder updated with grunt disabled.? Thanks guys. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely not normal. 
First - try to create new SailsJS application and check it once again. 
Second - check *Gruntfile.js* itself. Have you modified it and **path** in *config/local.js*?

Comment: I found the source of problem for this, that is Grunt was disabled in .sailsrc file. Is there a way where .tmp folder can be updated or changed with grunt disabled? I have asked the same in my previous comments. Thanks.

Comment: Are you referring to   

"hooks": {
    "grunt": false
  }? 

this doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, where grunt wasn't executing and updating .tmp folder.

In my case, the problem was that I cleaned by mistake grunt dependency in *package.json*:
**"grunt": "1.0.1",** and **"sails-hook-grunt": "^3.0.2",**

It restarted to work when I reintroduced the dependecies and execute npm install.

```
"dependencies": {
  "@sailshq/connect-redis": "^3.2.1",
  "@sailshq/lodash": "^3.10.3",
  "@sailshq/socket.io-redis": "^5.2.0",     
  "grunt": "1.0.1",
  "sails": "^1.0.2",
  "sails-hook-grunt": "^3.0.2",
  "sails-hook-orm": "^2.0.0-16",
  "sails-hook-sockets": "^1.4.0",
  "sails-mysql": "^1.0.0"
 },
```